# Why does TCP sender drop rate 50% on lost-packets?

Tags: tcp, packet-loss, congestion

Why is the standard TCP sender response to packet-loss (congestion), to drop 50% of the sending rate and then start working back up ?

If packet-loss was 20%, why not just drop 20% or maybe 25% to be safe ?

Comment: It is not the sending rate, it is the window size. It will still send at the same rate within the window, but it is just a half-size window.

Answer (score 3):

TCP adapts the receive window size when it detects congestion, ie. when packet loss occurs. There are several congestion algorithms, starting with the original *Tahoe*. An overview: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TCP_congestion_control.

What you're referring to is called the *additive-increase/multiplicative-decrease* (AIMD) algorithm. This basic model has been derived through simulations and has proven itself in the real world.

Basically, unless you *quickly* reduce traffic to a level *below* that which is causing congestion, the latter will dominate and suffocate the link.

The basic assumption is that *I was using the channel by myself before, and now there's another stream competing for bandwidth, so I'll reduce mine by 50%*. Since the sender has no way of knowing whether that is true or when the competing stream has ended, it tries to slowly increase its window/bandwidth again until congestion is detected again.

To date, this rather defensive way of treating shared bandwidth is the best way to handle the problem that's been found.

Here's a rather old paper but it's a good starter: https://www.icir.org/floyd/papers/sacks.pdf

Comment: I don't think this is really an answer just to say that a 50% reduction works best. Could you at least point to some paper which tested this compared to the approach I suggested? I suggest that dropping the packet rate by a little more than the current achieved packet rate should be enough to eliminate congestion.

Comment: @GroovyDotCom Check the updated answer for a starter link.